# Tailor ansible roles to environment

Tags: roles, ansible

I have a number of environments, that require a bunch of text files to be tailored in order for things like mule to speak to the right endpoints.

For this environment, this works:

```
ansible-playbook test03.yml
```

The only difference between an environment (from ansible's perspective) is the information held in ./roles/esb/vars/main.yml.

I've considered using svn to keep a vars/main.yml for each environment, so each time I need to configure an environment I check out roles and then vars/main.yml for that environment, before I run the command above.

To me, not an elegant solution. How can I do this better?

Directory structure

```
./test03.yml
./roles/esb/vars/main.yml
./roles/esb/tasks/main.yml
./roles/esb/templates/trp.properties.j2
```

./test03.yml

```
---
- hosts: test03-esb
  gather_facts: no
  roles:
    - esb
```

./roles/esb/vars/main.yml

```
---
  jndiProviderUrl: 'jnp://mqendpoint.company.com:1099'
  trp_endpoint_estask: 'http://tmfendpoint.company.com:8080/tmf/estask'
  trp_endpoint_builderQ: 'jnp://mqendpoint.company.com:1099'
```

./roles/esb/tasks/main.yml

```
---
  - name: replace variables in templates
    template: src=trp.properties.j2  dest=/path/to/mule/deploy/conf/trp.properties
```

./roles/esb/templates/trp.properties.j2

```
trp.endpoint.estask={{ trp_endpoint_estask }}
trp.endpoint.builderQ={{ trp_endpoint_builderQ }}
```

Comment: group_vars appears to hold some clues to this. I can't work out how to integrate this with the role. Also, include_vars, but I've given up trying to get this to work within the role.

Comment: I now have it sorted. I have my vars in file group_vars/test03 . I run ansible-playbook -i ~/hosts test03.yml and in ~/hosts I have [test03] \n servername and in test03.yml I simply point to the role.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

In order to use specific values for different environments all you need to do is move your variables from the role itself to a variables file for that specific enrivonment e.g.

```
production
|- group_vars
  |- servers
|- inventory
staging
|- group_vars
  |- servers
|- inventory
development
|- group_vars
  |- servers
|- inventory
roles
|- esb
  |- tasks
     |- main.yml
  |- templates
     |- trp.properties.j2
etc.
```

Inside each of the environments' `group_vars/servers` you could specify variable specific for that environment, e.g.

```
$ cat production/group_vars/servers
---
jndiProviderUrl: 'jnp://mqendpoint.company.com:1099'
trp_endpoint_estask: 'http://tmfendpoint.company.com:8080/tmf/estask'
trp_endpoint_builderQ: 'jnp://mqendpoint.company.com:1099'

$ cat staging/group_vars/servers
---
jndiProviderUrl: 'jnp://staging.mqendpoint.company.com:1099'
trp_endpoint_estask: 'http://staging.tmfendpoint.company.com:8080/tmf/estask'
trp_endpoint_builderQ: 'jnp://staging.mqendpoint.company.com:1099'

$ cat development/group_vars/servers
---
jndiProviderUrl: 'jnp://dev.mqendpoint.company.com:1099'
trp_endpoint_estask: 'http://dev.tmfendpoint.company.com:8080/tmf/estask'
trp_endpoint_builderQ: 'jnp://dev.mqendpoint.company.com:1099'
```

The Jinja2 template can then remain the same (it doesn't care where the variables come from after all).

You would then execute:

```
# Provision production
$ ansible-playbook $playbook -i production/inventory

# Provision staging
$ ansible-playbook $playbook -i staging/inventory

# Provision development
$ ansible-playbook $playbook -i development/inventory
```

Comment: Something missing from the execution. Usage: ansible-playbook playbook.yml. Do you mean ansible-playbook -i production/inventory production/esb.yml? esb.yml is a simple file, that merely glues "- hosts" argument to roles/esb.

Comment: Ah yes, sorry. You need to include the name of the playbook you wish to run. Have updated the answer :-)

Comment: @jabclab Is there some blog/gist, where the directory structure that you use is explained in further detail? I'm looking for a tutorial of sorts to get started on the right foot with the directory structure.

Comment: @jabclab: how do I set default vars?

Answer (score 4):

I tackle it this way

```
-inv
|
---prod
|
---qa
```

Then within the prod/qa inventory files, I specify top level groups like so:

```
#inv/prod
[prod:children]
#all the rest of prod groups

#inv/qa
[qa:children]
#all the qa groups
```

Which allows me to have the following group_var structure, where I keep all the relevant environment variables within these files (including 'env: qa' or 'env: prod', so I can perform operations based on the actual group membership, or based on the value of the env variable. The 'environment' variable is reserved and should not be used. Could also use the variable name 'stage' for this purpose.

```
inv
|
|
--group_vars
    |
    |
     ---qa
    |
     ---prod
```

When I run a playbook, I do it like this:

```
ansible-playbook appservers.yml -i inv/prod
```

Comment: I do the same thing - this is a good way to organise environment-specific variables.

Comment: I organise environment-specific variables using "<env>-<server_type>" (e.g. "staging-db" for the group names, with an inventory file for dev, staging, prod, etc, and directory under group_vars containing a secret.yml (Vault encrypted) and vars.yml.   For any more specific overrides I would use a different vars file included by the role/task. For a more complete description, see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32569456/992887).