# Complex environments with Ansible

Tags: deployment, configuration, ansible, production-environment

I've read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32526774/multistage-deployment-with-ansible) question and [this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-manage-multistage-environments-with-ansible) guide, but I still don't understand how to properly model our environment with ansible.

Our environment:

- Prod

  - A, B, C, D, E, F, G, each installed on its own server, plus a HA-backup
- Pre-Prod

  - A, B, C, D, E, F, G, each installed on its own server
- External Dev Instances (5 instances, sometimes more)

  - A, B, C, D, E, all installed on a single VM
  - F, G on a shared environment for ext-dev
- Internal Dev Instances (50+ instances)

  - A, B, C, D, E, F, G all installed on a single VM

Each of the parts A-G have lots of configuration key/value pairs spread over ~30 files, e.g. consisting of url/db-connection-strings/..., the hostnames of the other instances (A requires the name of hostname/port of B, etc) or various performance settings.

Many of the config key/value pairs are shared for dev instances, but not all. All external instances (Dev, Pre-Prod, Prod) share some further pairs.

How should I structure my environment so I can place all keys at the proper level , e.g. prod, ext-dev, in a way that I don't have to repeat the shared keys multiple times?

The existing answers above all seem to only work for simpler environments. And even if I create a complex structure like this:

```
env/
  prod/
    group_vars/
      all.yml
      a.yml
      b.yml
      c.yml
      d.yml
      e.yml
      f.yml
      g.yml
    hosts
  pre_prod/
    group_vars/
      all.yml
      a.yml
      b.yml
      c.yml
      d.yml
      e.yml
      f.yml
      g.yml
    hosts
  ext_dev/
    group_vars/
      all.yml
      abcd.yml
      fg.yml
    hosts
  int_dev/
    group_vars/
      all.yml
      abcdefg.yml
    hosts
roles/... [not important for this part]
playbook.yml
```

I cannot seem to properly set up the main playbook.yml file such that everything is correctly mapped. But I'm not sure what I am doing wrong, as this seems (to me) the proper mapping of the setup described in the two resources above to our environment.

Especially since some config items are instance-specific, some prod/dev/.. specific, some global.

**How should I set up our ansible project structure so it can handle our complex environment?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"How should I structure my environment so I can place all keys at the proper level , e.g. prod, ext-dev, in a way that I don't have to repeat the shared keys multiple times?"

You shouldn't.  The keys might have the same values now, but you cannot guarantee that they will always be the same in the future.

You will be better off separating your environments completely.

Comment: Please elaborate how a 'separate your environments completely' solution would look like, I don't understand.

Comment: You have a directory (or folder, if you prefer that term) for each environment.  Each of those directories has a `hosts` file and an `ansible.cfg` file.  We also keep a `group_vars` file there.  We have an `/etc/profile.d/ansible.sh` script which sets a `chinv` function.  That function sets the `ANSIBLE_INVENTORY` and `ANSIBLE_CONFIG` environment variables.  So we do `chinv /parent_dir/TEST2`, then we can change to the PLAYBOOKS directory and run playbooks from there.  The playbooks will only operate on the one environment specified by the ANSIBLE_INVENTORY variable.